# python selenium Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'

Tags: python, selenium

So I'm getting the error below using python selenium. I want to build a browsergame bot and I'm currently stuck here. Tried to do it mostly with the oop technique, but this didn't really work out for me since I had the bug only since I used the classes ;)

```js
Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'
```

My code:

```js
class Buildables():

 def __repr__(self):
  return self.sparte, self.toolTip

 def __init__(self, ref, sparte, *args, **kwargs):

  self.toolTip = lambda: wait.until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, ('//*[@ref=\'' + 
                str(ref) + '\']'))))

  self.LVL = lambda: int(
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, ('//* 
                [@ref=\'' + str(ref) + '\']/span/span')))).text)

  self.ausbauButton = lambda: wait.until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,
    ('//*[contains(text(),\' Ausbauen\')]'))))
  self.sparte = lambda : driver.find_element_by_xpath('//* 
                [contains(text(),'+ sparte +')]')


 metalMine = Buildables(1,'Versorgung')


 a = c.metalMine.sparte()
 a.click()
```

What do I do wrong?

BTW full error:

```js
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/leosc/PycharmProjects/ogameBot/ogame_main.py", line 5, in <module>
    cycles.buildMinesCycle()
  File "C:\Users\leosc\PycharmProjects\ogameBot\cycles.py", line 132, in buildMinesCycle
    a.click()
  File "C:\Users\leosc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Users\leosc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\leosc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\leosc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.
  (Session info: chrome=72.0.3626.121)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.46.628402 (536cd7adbad73a3783fdc2cab92ab2ba7ec361e1),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

Comment: Onwhich line are you getting this error ?

Comment: On the a.click() line

Comment: What's the output of `print(type(a))` and  `print(a)`, when you run them just before the `a.click()`? And why do you call `c.metalMine`'s `sparte()` method, when there object you instantiated is just "metalMine" - what's this "c" object, which apparently has the metalMine attribute?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, the c. refers to another file called classes, where I defined the class of the metalMine is an instance of. Anyhow, it works now, the problem was at [contains(text(),'+ sparte +')] where it needed to be [contains(text(),**\'**'+ sparte +'**\'**)]. But thanks alot anyway!!

Comment: Glad it did. By the way, both python and xpath support single and double quotes for strings - so you can use one for variable value delimiter, and the other inside it - this saving yourself some escaping hell. For example, this - `By.XPATH, ('//*[@ref=\'' + str(ref) + '\']')`, can be done like this: `By.XPATH, ('//*[@ref="' + str(ref) + '"]')`. And, that concatenation can be replaced with string formatting - `By.XPATH, ('//*[@ref="{}"]'.format(ref))`.